# uwp smart card extracting user information

Tags: uwp, buffer, smartcard, smartcard-reader

I am building a UWP app, and my aim is very simple. I have a connected smart card reader with my pc, so after running the app I want the user to insert his/her smart card into the smart card reader and then I want my app to extract all of their information ( i.e : firstname, lastname, address and other stuff like that ) in order to **automatically fill a form** and then so that they can be easily registered to my service, without having to right into every text box to fill all their information.

**What I Have tried so far**

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        string selector = SmartCardReader.GetDeviceSelector();
        DeviceInformationCollection devices =
            await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);
        var dialog = new MessageDialog("Number of devices : " + devices.Count.ToString());
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
        var device = devices[0];
        SmartCardReader reader =
            await SmartCardReader.FromIdAsync(device.Id);
        IReadOnlyList<SmartCard> cards =
            await reader.FindAllCardsAsync();
        var dialog2 = new MessageDialog("Number of cards in this device : " + cards.Count.ToString());
        await dialog2.ShowAsync();

        var card = cards[0];
        using (var conn = await card.ConnectAsync())
        {
            // after establishing connection, how can I extract the user information out of their smart cards?   
            var answer=await card.GetAnswerToResetAsync();
            // the above line is supposed to give a buffer can that be converted to string to extract out the requied data?
        }
        reader.CardAdded += Reader_CardAdded;
    }

    private void Reader_CardAdded(SmartCardReader sender, CardAddedEventArgs args)
    {
        //args has no method to extract data as well
    }
```

Comment: Do you intended, to issue the smart card yourself or are you considering health insurance cards credit cards etc? You know that in the latter case, even if the information is present on he card, you are not necessarily able to read it?

Comment: @guidot No we are not issuing smart cards ourself, we intend to read user data from "UAE id cards" those cards have chips on them and are smart cards, they do have a public sdk for .net to achieve this, but tht is built on .net framework 3.5 which isnt usable with uwp. so i looked into uwp smart card class, which is detecting card and reader well but i dnt know how to extract user data out of it

Comment: @guidot why cant we read it? do we need some sort of authentication? if yes then can you please redirect me where i can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dealing with smartcards in UWP is not so easy.

WinRT librarys only has Read and Write methods using bytes to communicate with the smartcard. There is no 'global high level' read or write operation for a smartcard.

For example, if you want to read a Mifare Classic smartcard, you will need to do several operations like authentication, reading certain blocks and sector to get/set data. All this steps are related to the Smartcard specification.

You need to find which standard "UAE id cards" uses and implement all low level operations (or find a library that makes it for you) using the Read and Write operations.

[Here](https://github.com/onovotny/MiFare) is an example of smartcard API to communicate with Mifare cards with UWP support. Note that are several steps to simply read and write data.